# Правильно ли определена грамматическая основа в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, сказуемые, подлежащее

"У него не было отца". 
Как мне кажется, то лексическое значение в том, что у него не было именно отца, поэтому грамматическая основа - "не было отца", но вот только сайт, на котором прорешиваю тесты, утверждает, что слово "отец" не является главным членом предложения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Грамматическая основа предложения — «не было». *Отца* — это прямое дополнение (несмотря на то, что оно стоит в родительном падеже — в таких случаях говорят, что он выполняет функцию винительного падежа).

Дело в том, что форма *отца* практически никогда не может выступать в роли подлежащего (а тем более сказуемого) в силу того, что, как правило, оно стоит в форме именительного падежа, а мы наблюдаем здесь родительный. На самом деле, все несколько сложнее, но для школьных целей такое обоснование удовлетворительно.

Answer (score 2):

**У него не было отца.**
Односоставное предложение, в котором один главный член — сказуемое "не было".
Это отрицательное безличное предложение: глагол в безличной форме (*было*) с отрицательной частицей "не" плюс дополнение в родительном падеже (*отца*).
[Типы односоставных предложений](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/707-18_dvusostavnye_i_odnosostavnye_predlozheniya_tipy_odnosostavnyh_predlozhenii.html)

У него не было денег. У них не осталось сил. Не хватило средств.